# Why do Java and C++ have syntactical similarities?

Tags: java, c++

I noticed that C++ and Java seem to have many features in common in terms of syntax, although I would assume them to be fairly different languages. For example, both languages support casting and define functions by specifying the return type and then the name of the function. The `for` loops also seem very similar. Also, they both use curly braces for a variety of statements and structures.

Is there a reason for this? Did Java and C++ have some common predecessor, or was the syntax of one based on the other, for example? Or am I just reading too much into this?

Comment: [Java was designed by people such as Jim Gosling who were very familiar with C and C++.](https://www.quora.com/Is-Java-similar-to-C-or-C++-in-any-way)

Comment: If memory serves, the syntax is similar so as to make C++ programmers feel comfortable with it.  Programmers are a conservative bunch, avoiding anything that's too unfamiliar. Many languages in the 1970s looked similar to Algol, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is just a member of the family of **C-style** languages (i.e. the languages syntactically based on C Programming Language). The family includes languages like

> C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP, Perl

which were very popular, for example, in 1990-s and the beginning of 2000-s.

Today's popularity of

> Python, Ruby, Rust, Kotlin, Swift and others.

slightly moved the focus away from C-style languages. One of the reasons to move away from C-style is that *C has context-dependent grammar* and the new languages tend to have almost *context-independent grammar*, which makes its parsing easier and more predictable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "C has context-dependent grammar and the new languages tend to have almost context-independent grammar, which makes its parsing easier and more predictable.", or provide a link to an article or something? I'm not really sure what you mean or in what way a language like, for example, Kotlin would be less "context-dependent" than Java?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone designing a new language would have nothing to gain by using different syntax for the same operations. So if the potential users of the language are, for example, used to "a++" being a variable "a" whose value increments but returns the existing value of a, or they're used to braces being what delimits a block of code, there's no reason for a new language not to use those same things. If this new language did switch these things, up, they risk potentially confusing and discouraging people from using it.

This extend not just to Java and C++, but some other languages as well. For example, JavaScript and Perl use many of the same syntax features that Java and C++ do.